# How to add form input data to a list in CodenameOne?

Tags: codenameone

In a CodenameOne project, I have the main form containing a list (or a multilist). On this form I also have a button to an insert entry form. On the insert entry form I have some input fields and a button to submit the form.

What I'm trying to achieve is, when I submit the insert entry form, the fields' data should be added as an item to the main form's list, and the main form should be shown again (I'm using the `back();` method for this.

Any hints on how this can be done? I've read the documentations and googled around, but I couldn't find nothing much helpful for a beginner in CodenameOne like me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the model of the list, override the initList callback where the model is set and define your own list model which stores the data in the way you want the data to be. Then the add operation can just modify that data structure.